# OEM Boot Image is Stretched

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04

There is new addition to version 20.04 that makes the boot image to show your laptop maker logo. However, the image is somehow stretched after passing grub option (I am on dual boot with Windows). Any way to fix this issue?

[image]

```
Laptop type : HP Probook 430 G5
OS : Ubuntu 20.04.1
BIOS Version : Q85 01.10.00
```